# Correlation with high weight to single features

Tags: correlation, matrix

I am a statistics newbie, so not sure how to appropriately frame this question or if it is too naive.

Essentially, I have a matrix of 500 items and each item has 8 numerical properties associated with it. I want to calculate all-vs-all pairwise similarities between these items such that even if one of the properties is significantly different for Item A vs Item B, then their pairwise similarity should be substantially reduced, regardless of how close the other properties are. I know that traditional correlation metrics like Pearsons and Spearman won't be able to do that, and as far as I understand unsupervised clustering methods like PCA/Hierarchical clustering using all 8 properties also will not downgrade a single metric. So what would be the appropriate way to go about doing this?

Comment: You seem to be describing a version of the [sup norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm). Although this is but one of many solutions, one advantage is that it truly is a metric. Another is that a weighted version is readily available.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you are looking for a nonparametric dependency measure between pairs of your 8 numerical properties (your feature variables). My proposal is that you bin each of your $8$ feature variables into meaningful histograms, each with $8-10$ equidistant intervals.

Now compute the mutual information among each $\frac{8\cdot 7}{2}=28$ possible pairs of feature variables. Define MI as

$
\begin{split}
MI(X;Y)=\sum_{y \in Y} \; \sum_{x \in X} \; p(x,y) \; log \left (\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x) \cdot p(y)} \right )
\end{split}
$

with $P(x,y)$ the bivariate histogram distribution for the pair of feature variables $X$ and $Y$, and $P(x),\; P(y)$ the histogram distributions for the individual variables $X$ and $Y$.

Sort your variable pairs based on $MI(X;Y)$, and you have a ranking for the inter-dependencies among your $8$ feature variables.

Comment: Why recommend binning--which loses information--and what's the basis for "8-10 equidistant intervals"?  This seems awfully *ad hoc.*

Comment: Thanks. If I understand this correctly, it will tell me which features are associated with each other across the 500 instances. Is that right? I'm not sure though how that leads to estimating distances between pairs of instances.

Comment: First, regarding 'binning' - the question begins with "correlation metrics like Pearsons and Spearman won't be able to do that..." indicating that a nonparametric analysis of probabilistic dependence is the logical next step. The numbers $8-10$ bins are not so arbitrarily chosen. I refer to Sturge’s Rule and for 500 observations end up with this number of bins, that is 8 till 10 bins for each variable.

Comment: "...I'm not sure though how that leads to estimating distances between pairs of instances...". This sub-question does not appear as part of your main question text. As soon as you leave the metric space and transform into binning space, a Hamming distance measure can be used instead. Recall that your begin premise was that the real-valued scale is unsuited for your application. A Hamming distance measure is coarse.

Comment: I'm sorry if that wasn't clear. The goal is to say whether A and B are very similar to each other, based on the similarity between their features. However, I need a way to bias the final similarity index by the number of dissimilarities between features rather than similarities. Crudely speaking in percentages, for example, if 7 features are similar but 1 is not, the final index shouldnt be (100*7)/8 = 87.5, but something lower. Realistically, the desired method would also consider the actual feature values to estimate the similarity index. I hope I'm making sense.